# Getting Access is denied error while using robocopy

Tags: robocopy

net use Z: https://mink.mycomp.com/EnUNew/G1/G2/G3/TestDocument ne569 /USER:mycmp\b569
Z:
dir
C:
robocopy \CODFS1.CON.EXACO.NET\SHARE\Dropbox\test\  Z:\ /MAXAGE:1 /E /XO 
net use Z: /d

I use the above code , I get Access is denied ERROR 5 (0x00000005).

How to get rid of the error . I am trying to copy a folder from a Sharedrive to a sharepoint site. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you doing this on Windows 2008 or later try using a Administrative command prompt. I just discovered this 'security feature' copying data from one server to another where I was admin on both